# I need a 10 second timer that will unlock a button when the timer ends

Tags: vb.net

I'm currently making a booking system is visual basic and i'm new to coding. After the user enters the incorrect username and password 3 times the login button locks. I need a 10 second timer that will start as soon as the button locks and after the timer ends, the button unlocks.

Code ----

```
     Private Sub lbllogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbllogin.Click
      While count <= 2
        If lblusern.Text = username And lblpwrd.Text = password Then 
            lblinvalidinput.Visible = False 
            Form2.Show() 
            Return
        Else
            lblinvalidinput.Visible = True 
            count = count + 1
            lblusern.Clear() 
            lblpwrd.Clear()  
            Return
        End If
    End While
    If count = 3 Then
        lbllogin.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Sean, and welcome to StackOverflow! There are a few ways to do this, what have you found? You might try searching something like "excel vba timer". That lead me here: (which has a really nice example) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timer-function

Comment: @seadoggie01 Interesting link, especially this bit "In Windows, the Timer function returns fractional portions of a second. On the Macintosh, timer resolution is one second" (!)

Comment: Typically these kind of systems have an increasing lock-out time based on the number of failed attempts. For example, after 3 failures then a 3 second lockout, but for every single failure attempt after the first three then double the previous lockout time; resetting when the password is entered correctly.

Comment: @seadoggie01, information about VBA is rather irrelevant when writing VB.NET code.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Oh, it was labeled as VBA before BigBen edited it... oops :)

Comment: Add a timer, set interval to 10s, start the timer, when timer ticks, do something.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is add Timer and Progressbar. Make sure to set default Timer Interval to 0 and Progressbar Value to 10.

```
Private Sub lbllogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbllogin.Click
      While count <= 2
        If lblusern.Text = username And lblpwrd.Text = password Then 
            lblinvalidinput.Visible = False 
            Form2.Show() 
            Return
        Else
            lblinvalidinput.Visible = True 
            count = count + 1
            lblusern.Clear() 
            lblpwrd.Clear()  
            Return
        End If
    End While
    If count = 3 Then
        lbllogin.Enabled = False
        Timer1.Interval = 1
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If Progressbar1.Value = 10 Then
        lbllogin.Enabled = True
        Timer1.Interval = 0
    Else
        Progressbar1.Value = Progressbar1.Value + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Or just set timer interval to 10s. He didn't say he needs a PB.

Comment: yup, a second thought, a label with countdown from 10s would look nice :) but still it's up to him.

Answer (score 0):

Upload your code with this:

```
 Private Sub lbllogin_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lbllogin.Click
        While count <= 2
            If lblusern.Text = username And lblpwrd.Text = password Then
                lblinvalidinput.Visible = False
                Form2.Show()
                Return
            Else
                lblinvalidinput.Visible = True
                count = count + 1
                lblusern.Clear()
                lblpwrd.Clear()
                Return
            End If
        End While
        If count = 3 Then
            lbllogin.Enabled = False
            timerUnlockStartMe(Nothing, Nothing)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub timerUnlockStartMe(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
        If sender Is Nothing Then
            Dim tmrUnlock As Timer = New Timer
            tmrUnlock.Interval = 10 * 1000 '10 seconds
            AddHandler tmrUnlock.Tick, AddressOf timerUnlockStartMe
            tmrUnlock.Start()
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ' do your what you want
        lbllogin.Enabled = True

        'and stop the timer
        CType(sender, Timer).Stop()
        CType(sender, Timer).Dispose()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Tasks for that

```
    Private Sub ReloadButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ReloadButton.Click
    sender.Enabled = False
    Dim _sample = Sample(5, Sub() Me.Invoke(Sub() sender.Enabled = True))
End Sub
Private Async Function Sample(_sec As Integer, f As [Delegate]) As Task
    Await Task.Delay(_sec * 1000)
    f.DynamicInvoke()
End Function
```